# Does left join suit here?

Tags: sql, asp.net

Here are my tables

### **Table 1: Patient**

```
id | pname  | plname |  cid
---+--------+--------+--------
1  | Savita |  rani  |  1
2  | Lavina |  kale  |  1
3  | fatima |  khole |  2
```

### **Table 2: DMRelation**

```
id | pid | did |  mid
---+-----+-----+-------
1  |  1  |  1  |   1
2  |  1  |  1  |   2
3  |  1  |  2  |   0
4  |  2  |  2  |   2
```

### **Table 3: Doctor**

```
id  |  dname
----+------------
1   |  Dr suhas
2   |  Dr Malini
```

### **Table 4: Medicine**

```
id | drugname
---+----------
1  |   Drug1
2  |   Drug2
```

I want show patientname along with doctorname and medicine name whose cid= 1.Whether doctor give or not give medicine to patient record should come.

### **QUERY**

```
select Patient.Pname,Doctor.dname,Medicine.Drugname
from DMRelation
inner join Patient
on Patient.id = DMRelation.pid
inner join Doctor
on Doctor.id = DMRelation.did
left join Medicine
on Medicine.id = DMRelation.mid
order by Patient.Pname,Doctor.dname,Medicine.Drugname
```

Comment: As I see, your query is good. whats the problem you facing?

Comment: Why are you putting 0 in foreign key column?

Comment: Your query should return exactly result you've described. And left join here is exactly what you need.

Comment: I assume that by `cid` you mean `mid`.

Comment: Thanks friend for ur reply.Actually I have given sample table.Actually I want to apply same logic for big table.If the logic is correct,i will go ahead.That's why I asked.Cid is not equal to mid.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the condition in the `on` clause may do what you want:

```
select p.Pname, d.dname, m.Drugname
from DMRelation r inner join
     Patient p
     on p.id = r.pid inner join
     Doctor d
     on d.id = r.did left join
     Medicine m
     on m.id = r.mid and m.id = 1
order by p.Pname, d.dname, m.Drugname;
```

This will return a list of doctors and patients, where the doctor has prescribed to the patient.  If doctor has prescribed the drug in question, then the name will appear.  Otherwise, it will be `NULL`.

If you want all patients, then you need to start with the `Patient` table and do `left join` all the way:

```
select p.Pname, d.dname, m.Drugname
from Patient p left join
     DMRelation r 
     on p.id = r.pid left join
     Doctor d
     on d.id = r.did left join
     Medicine m
     on m.id = r.mid and m.id = 1
order by p.Pname, d.dname, m.Drugname;
```

This will return all patients, with information specifically about the drug.